# how to rename folder in PHP The system cannot find the file specified. (code: 2)

Tags: php

If I change the site name, I want the folder name to change, how can I do that? i think this is changing the filename

```
$OldNameFolder=$path.$OldName;
$NewNameFolder=$path.$NewName;
rename('$OldNameFolder','$NewNameFolder');
```

Comment: When you enclose a "variable" in single quotes, it will not be treated as a variable in PHP. So `'$OldNameFolder'` is literally the characters enclosed and not the value of the variable. Same for your new name folder enclosed in single quotes. ... In Short, don't use single quotes. Use double quote marks. ... But in this code, you don't need any kind of quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try remove variables in string

```
rename($OldNameFolder,$NewNameFolder);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't enclose a variable as PHP will just think it's a string... So next time you should check if it's a variable before putting it in quotes :)

Comment: A variable can be enclosed in double quotes. It's just single quotes that treats it as literal characters.